# Changing tabs in C# code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

When an event is fired from an element on one tab, how can I have the handler switch the view to a different tab.

I am looking for how to do it in C# code, not xaml.  I have done research and cannot find a c# solution.

Comment: Can you show us that what you have tried   ?

Comment: Have you tried `tabControl.SelectedIndex`?

Comment: I tried it using SelectTab(index); as well as a few other examples I found online.  I did not realize the SelectedIndex could be set directly to an integer.  I'm new at WPF and thought if I minimized the amount of errors I showed than it would be more universally helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TabControl.SelectedIndex = <Integer index of the tab you want to display in the 0-based Tab array>`